# Netherlands residence permit while studying in Germany

Tags: resident-permit, netherlands

I am a Masters student in Germany and I have been offered a job in Netherlands. My employer is a recognized sponsor and is applying for my residence visa. They have submitted my documents to IND a week ago.

Now for some family reasons I need to go to India as soon as possible. So, now my question is can I go to India while my visa process on going for Netherlands ? I also got to know that, my employer will book an appointment to IND Desk in Den bosch once they receive a reply from IND.

My work contract is starting from 1st May 2021. So, I must need to book an appointment to IND desk before 1st May or I can take an appointment even after 1st May ? What can I do in this situation considering the fact that I need to go to India as soon as possible?

Does anyone have any idea about it? Or someone who has passed from this type of situation? Please give your suggestion.

Comment: Can you give some information about your status in Germany?  Is your residence permit or visa still valid?  Will it be valid through April 30th?

Comment: Hi, I do have German resident permit valid for next 1 year

Comment: Why are you worried then?  Do you have any reason to think you would have trouble reentering the Schengen area with the German residence permit?

Comment: I am actually not worryied about coming back. I am worried about having a valid resident permit of Netherlands before starting my work. Probably I also need to submit Biomatrix to Netherlands immigration before getting valid resident permit. In that case, should I go to my country? Or not. Both things are very important right now. I'm in dilemma.